# Should I set max pool size in database connection string? What happens if I don't?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connection-string, connection-pooling

This is my database connection string. I did not set max pool size until now.

```
public static string srConnectionString = 
                       "server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=sa;pwd=mypw;";
```

So currently how many connections does my application support? What is the correct syntax for increasing the connection pool size?

The application is written in C# 4.0.

Comment: if you don't have a problem, leave it as the default.

Comment: currently yes but i think it might cause problems at peak moments. So i prefer set higher than default. as i read default is 100 am i right ?

Comment: The default Connection Pool size of 100 is documented by Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling and likely other places.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Currently your application support 100 connections in pool. Here is what conn string will look like if you want to increase it to 200:

```
public static string srConnectionString = 
                "server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=sa;pwd=mypw;Max Pool Size=200;";
```

You can investigate how many connections with database your application use, by executing `sp_who` procedure in your database. In most cases default connection pool size will be enough.

Comment: Is there another way of setting the Max and Min poolsize than via the connectionstring? I would prefer to do it in code...

Comment: What happens when setting the 'max pool size' to, let say 30. When all the slots filled with 'in-use' and 'idle connections', will the idle connections be closed automatically to make room for new connections?

Comment: @Pierre - you'll receive an error similar to the following:

System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. 

This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionPoolManager.GetPooledConnection(SqlConnectionString options, Boolean& isInTransaction)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

Comment: What is your reference for 100 connections by default?

Comment: The first paragraph of the "Adding Connections" section of the Documentation article SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET) states that 100 is the default max pool size. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#adding-connections) Seen 2019-09-14

Comment: In most cases, you want a smaller rather than bigger pool size, your database only has so many threads that it can use to process your request. By default "Pool Size = # of cores * 2 +1". There is a great explanation for that in the HikariCP documentation https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Answer (score 17):

*"currently yes but i think it might cause problems at peak moments"*
I can confirm, that I had a problem where I got timeouts because of peak requests. After I set the max pool size, the application ran without any problems.
IIS 7.5 / ASP.Net

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score -7):

We can define maximum pool size in following way:

```
                <pool> 
               <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
```

Comment: What file is this?

Comment: it is not clear that what file is this, if it is a webconfig then where should we add this <pool> tag.